# Flutter: JSObject ([object Promise]) - how to proceed?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to check if the user is using an InPrivate/incognito mode on Flutter web. The code from [here](https://github.com/Joe12387/detectIncognito/blob/main/detectIncognito.js) appears to be working.

The JS code is as follows (partial code):

```
var detectIncognito = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var browserName = "Unknown";
        function __callback(isPrivate) {
            resolve({
                isPrivate: isPrivate,
                browserName: browserName,
            });
        }
```

in Flutter when I call this function:

```
var res = js.context.callMethod('detectIncognito');
```

'res' shows up as a 'JSObject ([object Promise])'

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The complete code, with minor edits, from @aminjafri-dev's detailed analysis is:

```
@JS()
library detectIncognito;

import 'dart:js_util';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; // for debugPrint
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
@anonymous
class DetectIncognitoResult {
  external bool get isPrivate;
  external String get browserName;
  external factory DetectIncognitoResult({bool isPrivate, String browserName});
}

@JS()
external DetectIncognitoResult detectIncognito();

Future<bool> checkPrivateBrowsing() async {
  bool isPrivate = false;

  await promiseToFuture(detectIncognito()).then((result) {
    isPrivate = result.isPrivate;
    debugPrint('${result.browserName}'); // I dont need this returned
  });
  return isPrivate;
}
```

and called as

```
bool isPrivate = await checkPrivateBrowsing();
```